# Matching numerical methods to numerical solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I've been given a problem regarding numerical analysis techniques for solving ODEs. My professor has not introduced the concept of choosing the method to use based on system of ODEs.

I have just today been introduced to the concept of stiffness and how it applies somewhat generally to linear systems of ODEs based on negative real parts of both eigenvalues. System 1, as I understand, is stiff, but has a relatively low stiffness ratio. System 2 does not meet the stiffness criteria. System 3, however, has one negative eigenvalue and one eigenvalue equal to zero. Does this mean it has an incredibly high stiffness ratio? I assume more "stable" methods (eg backward Euler or midpoint method) should be used for stiffer systems. I have outlined the question below.

Assume that you can use three ODE solvers, the forward Euler, the backward Euler and the midpoint method. Which one should you use for the system of ODE’s (and why) y' = Ay where A is:

1) [ [-2, 1], [1, -2] ]

2) [ [0, 1], [-1, 0] ]

3) [ [-10^3, 1], [1, -10^(-3)] ]

[Photo of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2bd7.png)

Comment: What ideas do you have? Have you tried applying the 3 solvers to these systems?

Comment: My first thought was to solve for eigenvalues. For number 1, the eigenvalues are both negative, so the backward Euler is unconditionally stable. For the second, I think the system is oscillating? I am not confident on this one and as far as I know all three of the methods are unstable when the system involves purely imaginary eigenvalues. The last one has one eigenvalue equal to zero which is not a concept I am familiar with. The other has a large magnitude (~1000) and is negative. I am unsure about the stability of any of the methods given that one of the eigenvalues is zero in this case.

Comment: Also I have not tried to apply any of the solvers. The class I am in is an introductory class to ODEs and we have done very little actual coding of these methods. I apologize if I am using incorrect terminology or if my questions are unclear.

Comment: I am not able to answer your question myself but the additional effort you have shown should attract answers. If you don't get one within 24 hours I recommend that you edit your comments into your question. Edits bring your question back to the top of the Home Page.

Comment: Thank you for the info!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the given restrictions on method selection, there is never a good reason to prefer the Euler methods (except as an introduction to numerical methods).

The third problem is stiff, thus will give a better result at large step sizes with an implicit method. With the limited selection, this is the implicit Euler method.